# htaccess, how to hide php extensions

Tags: apache2, php

I am trying to use the .htaccess file to hide php extensions but it doesn't seem to be working.   It does work if there is a html file in the directory and I don't use the .html extension.

This is what I have.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

So

```
http://www.mydomain.com/test
```

Should bring up.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/test.php
```

It says:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /test was not found on this server.
```

Comment: How about `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$` instead of `^([^/.]+)$`. It's kinda what works out for me.

Comment: So both of these work on here... http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ which is what I've been used to validate... but it still gives me Not Found... The requested URL /test was not found on this server.   Is there something overriding it?  I've done chmod 664 on the .htaccess file..

Comment: Okay I figured it out finally.... taking out MultiViews from the conf file for the site did it.   I'm assuming I still need the htaccess entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the conf file for the site, I was able to fix this by taking out MultiViews.   Then it started working normally.

Answer (score 2):

I have my own HomeServer with Ubuntu Server and this it how I did it.

1. You need to edit the apache2 config file located in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```
2. You have to edit the line that look like that:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/html/>
     Option Indexes FollowSymbLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

   - You need to replace the `AllowOverride None` with `AllowOverride All`, then you need to enable rewrite mode in apache2 in the terminal:

     ```
     sudo a2enmod rewrite
     ```
3. then restart apache service

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Try now, it should work.

Comment: This worked EXCEPT:  change AllowOverride None  to  AllowOverride All    I'm guessing it's just a typo :)  But the real fix for me was taking out the MultiViews

Comment: Thanks !!! Save My Day :)